# Why am I getting false all the time?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Password hash is working and its storing correctly
But while comparing the res is always returning false
Even though the password is correct. I am using bcryptjs for hashing

```
app.post("/api/register", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, school, phone, password } = req.body;
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function (err, hash) {
      con.query(
        `INSERT INTO users(uid, u_name, u_email, u_school, u_phone, u_password) VALUES ('[value-1]','${name}','${email}','${school}','${phone}','${hash}')`,
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(result);
        }
      );
    });
  });
});
app.post("/api/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  con.query(
    `SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_email='${email}'`,
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err.sqlMessage).end();
      } else {
        bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].u_password).then((res) => {
          console.log(res);
      });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: have you tried logging out what `result[0].u_password` is? it could be undefined

Comment: yes it returned something like this: $2a$10$IaiCd6FFn/Z6RZBUTL93jON

Comment: are you comparing to the an encrypted password? or passing the password as it is typed? you can console log the password. But basically those two values do not equal eachother so you are getting false

Comment: bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].u_password) password='1234' result[0].u_password is the encrypted one

Comment: $2a$10$RkUHTh90A4neEz9mvg2gVea      //console.log(result[0].u_password);
1234      //console.log(password);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response.
I found the mistake it was in my database.
I limit my password varchar(30) but the string size was 60 thats why it was not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to hash the password variable before you compare it in the login route. Otherwise you're comparing a hash and a string and those do not mix.